# Spark streaming, how to see JMX metrics in UI

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I have configured jmx metrics in spark streaming application. Following is the code :

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled", "true")
    spark.conf.set(s"spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.jmx.class", "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink")

    UserMetricsSystem.initialize(sc, config.getAppNamespace)
    val listener = new EventCollector(isSingleStream) // Some custom code
    spark.streams.addListener(listener)
```

With metrics.properties contents are :

```
*.sink.jmx.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

After configuring all this and running the application, I can see inputRate, latency and processingRate for the application on:

```
 jconsole <host>:<port> // driver host
```

But I want to see those metrics in json format on browser.
Is there a way to access these configured jmx metrics through spark API?